# Unable to configure Visual Studio Team Services Azure Hosted Agents

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up a Hosted Agent to do our CI/CD builds but it doesn't look like the Azure Portal is allowing me.

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/get-more-build-or-load-testing-vs).

I'm using the new Portal and on Step 4, the Hosted Agents drop down doesn't appear when I select Paid. In fact nothing happens, the save icon stays inactive,

I've tried with Chrome ( 50.0.2661.94), Edge and IE 11 to no avail.

It does look like an issue on Microsoft's end but I'm just wondering whether there is something that I should be doing that I'm not doing

Comment: I can reproduce this issue, so this is not caused by your settings. I will update the information if I get more finding on this.

Comment: Microsoft is working on investigating this issue, refer to this link for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/05/10/issues-with-purchasing-build-agents-on-visual-studio-team-services-510-investigating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed now, please clear the cookies&cache in your browser and then try to configure it.

> Final Update: Thursday, 12 May 2016 07:54 UTC
>
> We’ve deployed the fix in production and confirmed that  the issue is
>   mitigated. Customers are requested to delete cookies and clear cache
>   in the browsers before trying the workflow . We are investigating root
>   cause to prevent any recurrence.